# can we use the limit to find the maximum of a function?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I am just wondering if we can find the maximum of function in [0,+inf] if this function is monotonically increasing by just finding the limit ( lim(x-->+inf) )

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

If you *truly* mean the function to be defined on $[0,\infty]$, then the hypothesis of being weakly increasing implies that its maximum on $[0,\infty]$ is just $f(\infty)$.

If you mean the function to be defined on $[0,\infty)$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ will be the least upper bound of $f$ over $[0,\infty)$, which is its maximum on $[0,\infty)$ if and only if $f$ is eventually constant as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I meant the second one . thank you for the answer!